# Stack Exchange Android app cannot run on Android 12

Tags: support, android-app

***Preface**: I acknowledge that [the official mobile apps are no longer supported by Stack Exchange and no proper bug fixes will be deployed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353133/241919). This is more for documentation/announcement (and possibly a heads-up, and finding a workaround if any) since Android supports sideloading an app and some are still using it exclusively for the push notifications. It also serves as a duplicate target for future such reports.*

---

On the final version of the Stack Exchange Android app, v1.0.95, the app crashes on startup on Android 12 while it's still (kind of) working on older Android versions.

According to the logcat, this is due to improper initialization of Fabrics/Crashlytics, a 3rd-party library for reporting crashes (which is somewhat ironic).

```
10-21 09:18:09.967 28168 28168 E Fabric  : Crashlytics must be initialized by calling Fabric.with(Context) prior to calling Crashlytics.getInstance()
10-21 09:18:09.967 28168 28168 D AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
10-21 09:18:09.967 28168 28168 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-21 09:18:09.967 28168 28168 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.stackexchange.marvin, PID: 28168
10-21 09:18:09.967 28168 28168 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Must Initialize Fabric before using singleton()
10-21 09:18:09.967 28168 28168 E AndroidRuntime:        at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.singleton(Fabric.java:254)
10-21 09:18:09.967 28168 28168 E AndroidRuntime:        at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.getKit(Fabric.java:502)
10-21 09:18:09.967 28168 28168 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics.getInstance(Crashlytics.java:432)
10-21 09:18:09.967 28168 28168 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics.isDisabled(Crashlytics.java:1074)
10-21 09:18:09.967 28168 28168 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics.doLog(Crashlytics.java:486)
10-21 09:18:09.967 28168 28168 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics.log(Crashlytics.java:482)
10-21 09:18:09.967 28168 28168 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.stackexchange.marvin.utils.Helpers.log(Helpers.java:186)
10-21 09:18:09.967 28168 28168 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.stackexchange.marvin.utils.Helpers.log(Helpers.java:190)
10-21 09:18:09.967 28168 28168 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.stackexchange.marvin.Current$1.onConnected(Current.java:246)
```

While proper fixes cannot be expected, something like a workaround will be appreciated.

Comment: Quick note - we were discussing this on chat, and for those of us still using the app, having some documentation of *when* it broke is probably useful.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I posted [this chat message](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=9042539#9042539) on the day it broke, October 20.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that. It probably broke 'earlier' tho, Just that folks are seeing failures as they upgrade to android 12

Comment: What is wrong with this, and why isn't this a dupe of it: [How can I report bugs with or request features for the Stack Exchange mobile apps?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348075/how-can-i-report-bugs-with-or-request-features-for-the-stack-exchange-mobile-app)

Comment: Sorry not sure what's the point here? The horse is dead. Bury it and let it rest in peace.

Comment: *Broke* [6 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34278151/3648282), the incorrect call is simply being caught now.

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsVaccinatedV3 - If people are still using the app, like me, this is *literally* the point where the app is unusable for *everyone*  still using it. No "It does notifications then it crashes", no "It *could* work....  In addition since android 12 upgrades don't happen all at once it gives something searchable.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek still using horse metaphor... you were just riding a dead horse all those years, fact he kept going was just a miracle, never intended by its creator. I don't have anything against it, but still consider this the same as all bug reports since the official declaration about the app death. This just happens to be a bigger bug. People can still, in theory, just use a device with lower version of android and "enjoy" the app. (And remember to never let the device update to 12 ;))

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I report bugs with or request features for the Stack Exchange mobile apps?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348075/how-can-i-report-bugs-with-or-request-features-for-the-stack-exchange-mobile-app)

Comment: @Luuklag The top part of the post explains why it's not a duplicate of the general "app is unsupported" posts. Can you please explain why you believe that explanation to be inadequate?

Comment: "this is a documentation" That's not something that we really need. I see value in this as a "signpost" because mentioning Android 12, but thats about it. @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog

Comment: And what about the clause in the proposed duplicate that says that "*...[[tag:support]] questions can still be asked, and perhaps the community here knows a workaround for your [[tag:bug]]*"? I think this question is a perfect fit for that clause, so... if we're not going to respect it, it should really be removed. Otherwise, this question should stay open.