# Is/could the "Android/iOS" application endpoint for notifications be opened up to other apps?

Tags: feature-request, android-app, ios-app, notifications, api

The Android application is *quite* dead for me (but not to me) - I've been messing with an alternate app, but the lack of notifications is still a pain.

The 'long term' alternative would be to get [web push notifications](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/321093/now-that-the-mobile-apps-are-no-longer-in-development-could-we-get-web-push) as suggested, but that's going to take an indefinite amount of time to be a thing.

In [discussing alternatives with the dev of another, unofficial SE client](https://github.com/tylerbwong/stack/issues/120), it was mentioned that

> Would love to bring push notifications to the app, but unfortunately part of this implementation requires server-side implementation of Firebase Cloud Messaging. It seems like things are still up and running on the Stack Exchange side, but I'm not sure if the API to register a device for push is public.

It's a bit of a strange thing to ask, and I know lots of the mobile APIs still secret squirrel, but would it be an option to informally (or formally!) open this up, and give some heads-up before the notifications API and backend is sunset?

Comment: Related: [iPhone push notifications - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/394972/iphone-push-notifications)

Answer (score 7):

For iOS, the answer is definitely no; push notifications are sent to an app with a specific identifier, namely `com.stackexchange.stackexchange` and there's no way someone else could register that application identifier and 'spoof' the official app. You *could* compile the source code of an app yourself, and use a wildcard certificate to install it on your personal device, but wildcard certificates don't support push notifications.

My Android skills are a bit rusty, but I doubt it would be possible there. It seems to violate some of the integrity of the ecosystem (OS and apps) but I'm happy to be proven wrong.

Right now, I have the app running on three devices, including my day-to-day smartphone (an iPhone 11). I know that someday I will need to replace the device, and not be able to install the iOS app anymore (restoring from backup won't work either). My backup plan for that: have my server login to a Stack Exchange site directly and monitor the [inbox WebSocket](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/218355/295232), and use [another app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/318926/295232) to send the push notifications. Probably with some filter to suppress non-urgent messages... But I hope Stack Exchange will implement web push notifications before that happens.

Comment: Well - if I could code, I'd do that but .... yeah, I'd actually be ok with running stuff on my server and sending it over to my phone. I'd jokingly suggest a matrix bridge but ... that's just me