# How about getting your inbox notifications on Android phone?

Tags: feature-request, notifications, android

We [know](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383026/260388) that Stack Exchange has discontinued its Android App and is [not interested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315791/260388) in making the app code open source.

One of the greatest features of the app, that I am missing most, is the instant notifications it used to send, and I believe it's worth having such a feature again. I think I could participate more actively if I get notifications where action may be required.

**Even if one doesn't have features like posting, commenting, editing, moderating the site but if one can get notifications, s/he can log in the mobile browser and can do all the activities.**

This will improve the post activity and engagement of users on our communities.

So, it would be useful if one can just get notification and clicking on which opens the browser navigating that post.

Comment: Very much related: [Now that the mobile apps are no longer in development ... Could we get Web Push Notifications?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/321093/now-that-the-mobile-apps-are-no-longer-in-development-could-we-get-web-push)

Comment: Are you asking for new "mini app" that will have only notifications? Or for something based on a browser? Also, why only android, when great many people use iOS based devices?

Comment: Well - he uses android, an iOS app would be a different request unless... There was a near universal way to do it... Which is what I suggested.

Comment: @ShadowTheGPTWizard mini app is feature request yes. Let's name it "Stack Inbox". Something based on browser may be off-topic for MSE?

Comment: Its a feature that benefits established users mainly - and honestly I'm still not convinced that's a priority for the company.

Comment: Is the company's priority its users?

Comment: Well - my request is almost 5 years old. In that period apple got web push notifications working on ios. See also my [post here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/391832/what-are-some-deferred-ignored-or-sunset-projects-we-wish-se-would-work-on-to) and a good many community requests other than that. Then compare it to what the company is doing and working on.

Comment: I'm using a web app using Chrome for Android that send me notifications on my Android, similar to WhatsApp notifications.. I haven't to install anything extra, just to turn on notifications on the web app pop up shown the first time I logged in.

Comment: @Wicket Does it still work when you close the browser? I think browser should keep running in background to work. Anyway that would be a solution for some users however I think a small independent app isolated from browser would be good idea.

Comment: @Wicket That's what web push notifications are. And yeah, they worked with the browser closed

Comment: @Pandya  See above comment. Besides being good idea the product manager should look for cost - effective solutions. Not sure what option will be better in the long term.

Comment: Related: [iPhone push notifications - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/394972/iphone-push-notifications)